# How to formate dat file to turn into clean csv

Tags: python

I had a dat file of the following format

```
1963.00000       0.18983       0.25000
   0.24558       0.32248    1708.03226
 127.40000      34.50000     847.67600
 686.93106      16.48359       0.94900
   0.24800       0.05374       2.00000
   0.25000      74.88000       0.05300
1907.12000      67.16000       0.18446
   0.71540       0.32174    2036.00000

1964.00000       0.19803       0.25700
   0.24710       0.35442    1859.92520
 138.50000      38.40000     928.97276
 727.71924      18.04516       0.94787
   0.25400       0.05499       3.00000
   0.27000      76.96498       0.04500
2030.77821      68.44358       0.18556
   0.42009       0.34896    2139.00000
```

I would like to put that file in csv but not in that format but instead like that  : 
1963.00000       0.18983       0.25000     0.24558       0.32248    1708.03226 ...  0.71540       0.32174    2036.00000

This is for turn that dat file into clean CSV with each value of that one line become a column

```
file =  'Downloads/Données.dat'
lst = []
with open(path) as f :
  for line in f:
      lst += [line.split()]
```

i just loaded file because i'm stuck with that issue and i'm beginner in text processing.

i would like to concat each block of 8 lines into 1 lines

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
datfile = 'Downloads/Données.dat'
lst = []
with open(datfile) as f:
    data = f.read()
    lst += [" ".join(row) for row in [block.split() for block in data.split("\n\n")]]
for line in lst:
    print(line)
```